# Javascript Array four elements but display in console and accessible only three

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got an very obscure problem

I have an Array with 4 elements, each is Array

[image]

`Console.log` display 4 arrays but the number of elements is **only 3**

[image]

This is my code:

```
 var locations = [];$.each(result,function (index,value) { //add 1st,2nd,3th elements - 
                    locations.push([
                        value.displayValue,
                        value.posX,//lat
                        value.posY,//long
                        3
                    ]);
                    locationDatasource.push({
                        indexing: (index+1),    
                        lat:value.posX,//lat
                        long:value.posY,//long
                    });
                });
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    
                    locations.push([ //add custom test elements - current location
                        "test",
                        position.coords.latitude,//lat
                        position.coords.longitude,//long
                        3
                    ]);
                    locationDatasource.push({
                        indexing: 9,
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,//lat
                        long:position.coords.longitude,//long
                    });
                });


console.log(locations);//
```

I've tried to `$.each` the `locations` but I got only 3 too:

[image]

So what is my wrong? Thank you very much!

**UPDATE for @vlad comment**

This is my result (get from my appservices)

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show the result of console.log(result)

Comment: @vladkatz I've update! let see

Comment: See that blue `i` icon, click on it, it says the values are updated after the values are printed in console. When you expand the array, you see the updated values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you expand something in the console, if the thing that was logged has been updated since the log, it will show the updated value (as long as it's not a primitive - a string, number, etc. - but an object or an array will).  Because you do:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    locations.push(/* ... */);
})
console.log(locations);
```

it seems pretty clear to me that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous.  So basically at the point you do `console.log(locations)` the length *is* 3.  By the time you expand it, `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` has completed, and the length is now 4.

You can verify this by doing

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(locations));
```

and you will see there are only 3 elements (as this won't see any updates)

Comment: thank you, I forgot the most important that "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition" is asynchronous