# Async model loading with Three.js -- model doesn't seem to fully load

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, three.js

I have a .gltf file that I'm trying to render in WebGL.  I followed the Three.js tutorial [here](https://discoverthreejs.com/book/first-steps/load-models/) and my 3d model looks like this:

[image]

So the left ear and ears are completely invisible and missing textures.  I suspect that the model isn't loading properly before I add it to the scene.

My World.js file looks like:

```
import { loadModels } from './components/birds/birds.js';
import { createCamera } from './components/camera.js';
import { createLights } from './components/lights.js';
import { createScene } from './components/scene.js';

import { createControls } from './systems/controls.js';
import { createRenderer } from './systems/renderer.js';
import { Resizer } from './systems/Resizer.js';
import { Loop } from './systems/Loop.js';

let camera;
let controls;
let renderer;
let scene;
let loop;

class World {
  constructor(container) {
    camera = createCamera();
    renderer = createRenderer();
    scene = createScene();
    loop = new Loop(camera, scene, renderer);
    container.append(renderer.domElement);

    controls = createControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    const { ambientLight, mainLight } = createLights();

    loop.updatables.push(controls);
    scene.add(ambientLight, mainLight);

    const resizer = new Resizer(container, camera, renderer);
  }

  render() {
    mainLight.position.copy(camera.position);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }

  async init() {
    console.log('Initializing world');
    const models = await loadModels();
        
    console.log('Adding models to scene');

    models.models.forEach((model) => {
      console.log(model);
      scene.add(model);
    });

    //controls.target.copy(models[0].position);
  }

  start() {
    loop.start();
  }

  stop() {
    loop.stop();
  }
}

export { World };
```

And `loadModels()` looks like:

```
async function loadModels() {
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();

    const modelData = await loader.loadAsync('https://myurl.com/cat.gltf');
    
    const models = modelData.scene.children;

    console.log("Models found within source file");
    console.log(models);

    return { models }
}
```

[image]

I noticed that the Arrays say there are 6 objects in the array but I only see 3 objects in the log -- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63370097/javascript-array-four-elements-but-display-in-console-and-accessible-only-three) thread suggest that at the time my code runs, only 3 meshes have loaded, but because of how I'm logging, it updates after the fact to tell me there are six elements.

I double-checked the .gltf file in Blender, and the file is correctly formatted (I even checked the normals to see if they were inverted and back-culling was the issue):

[image]

It is clear from the blender file that the object has 6 models within the file, but for whatever reason only 3 ever load.  I would assume that the async function `loadModels()` with the `await` keyword would mean that I wouldn't run into the async problem... but it seems like I still am?

What can I do to amend this situation?

Edit: link to 3d model here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1crTC6ADUEynRd8CftF7UTbhYXBxrngXC/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Does the asset load correctly at this page: https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/ ? Besides, do you mind sharing the glTF asset in this thread?

Comment: It works perfectly there!  I edited the original post with a link to the 3d model